# Where is the 'main' function located?

Tags: c

Where is the '`main`' function located?

```
int main() {
    const char *str = "hello world";
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

I know about these locations:

- `.text`
- `.data`
- `.bss`
- `stack`
- `heap`

I think that the answer is `.bss` because I know '`main`' function is not located in others (but I might be wrong).

Comment: Do you know what these sections mean?

Comment: It is in the .text section.  The other ones are used for data, this is code.

Comment: Honestly I understand only stack and heap. Text data bss are not familiar with me

Comment: Can you explain them a little bit on the answer? I cant search for .text things on google.

Comment: There is nothing like that in the C language. Your platform probanly places executable code in .text, but who knows.

Comment: Who knows??? I have to know this concept to design OS.

Comment: The term to google is "ELF".

Comment: So why are you asking about C? It's an OS concept. An OS doesn't care which language your machine code was written.

Comment: Because I'll be writing C and x86 to build OS. And what do you mean??

Comment: Please feel free to edit my question if anything is unclear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is obviously outside the realms of C standard because it doesn't mention any "sections".

Using [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) systems as an example, typically all the code will be in [text segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) (also known as code segment) and `main` will be in text segment. You can look at where the symbols reside by using `readelf` or `objdump` commands. For example, if you inspect the output of `objdump -S a.out` you can see assembly and various sections.

You can read  http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF and http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f00/docs/elf.pdf for further info.